# Change column values in r datatable based on numeric inputs

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to allow the users to see the changes in inputs to be reflected on the table directly. So as soon as the user changes numeric value for input`lower` it should reflect the change in column lower_rate in the table and also multiply that value with `low_val`. Is this possible with `observeEvent` on numeric input change.

````
input_data <- data.frame(lower_rate = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         low_val = c(10,11,12),
                         upper_rate = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5),
                         upp_val = c(20,21,22),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),



    # Create a new row for the table.
    fluidRow(
      column(12,

             numericInput("low", label = h3("lower"), value = 0.5),
             numericInput("up", label = h3("Upper"), value = 1.5),
             dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
      )
    )    
  )  
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  d <- reactive({
    input_data
  })

  dat <- reactiveValues(dat=NULL)
  observe({
    dat$dat <- d()
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    dat$dat
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be best to edit the column value inside the reactive environment `renderDataTable`. The observe events are not needed. As long as you don't use the `<<-` notation to write to environment, this wont change the original data.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

input_data <- data.frame(lower_rate = c(.5, .5, .5),
                         low_val = c(10,11,12),
                         upper_rate = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5),
                         upp_val = c(20,21,22),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),



    # Create a new row for the table.
    fluidRow(
      column(12,

             numericInput("low", label = h3("lower"), value = 0.5),
             numericInput("up", label = h3("Upper"), value = 1.5),
             dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
      )
    )    
  )  
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    input_data$lower_rate <- input$low
    #it is not clear where you want the multiplied value to end up
    input_data$new_val <-  input$low*input_data$low_val
    data.table(input_data)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```